# How to use OR condition in where query in Flutter Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart

I just wanna make a query in Firebase flutter by two dynamic fields in the same Where in, can anyone help me?

```
  body: StreamBuilder(
   stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("ownerchat").
   where("key.userid || key.senderid",whereIn: [widget.myid])
       .snapshots(),
    builder: (ctx, snapShot) {
      if (snapShot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return SpinKitCircle(
          color: Colors.blue,
        );
      }

      final docs = snapShot.data.docs;
      return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) =>
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  pp=docs[index]["keyy"];
                  username = docs[index]['username'];
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (ctx) => chatmain(username, pp)));
                },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have such *or* operator in Firestore, you have two `where` streams excluding each other:

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("ownerchat").
                    where("key.userid",isEqualTo: widget.myid).snapshots()
```

and

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("ownerchat").
                    where("key.senderid",isEqualTo: widget.myid).snapshots()
```

you can get the results with two streams, and for example merge the streams together or combine result in one list.

Answer (score 0):

**Limitations**

Note the following limitations for in, not-in, and array-contains-any:

1. in, not-in, and array-contains-any support up to 10 comparison values.
2. You can use at most one array-contains clause per query. You can't combine
   array-contains with array-contains-any.
3. You can use at most one in, not-in, or array-contains-any clause per query. You can't combine these operators in the same query.
4. You can't combine not-in with not equals !=.
5. You can't order your query by a field included in an equality (==) or in clause.

Comment: You cannot use 'whereIn' filters more than once. i got this error

Comment: are you querying in arrays or fields?

Comment: https://imgurl.me/image/D1PXg                                                                                                                            i make in firestore Filed type Map contains 2 filed type string (userid and senderid) and now i wanna display this fileds where uid=id